# Tailwind css Intellisense not working when use with daisyui

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vscode-extensions, daisyui

I am using tailwind css + daisyui with IDE: VSCode
And I have tailwind.config.js below. But my extension **Tailwind css Intellisense** before I install daisyui is work perfectly. But when daisyui is installed and configured, my extension still not work anymore.
Another problem prettier still not work too.

Please help me solve my problem

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "node_modules/daisyui/dist/**/*.js",
    "node_modules/react-daisyui/dist/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      inter: ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
      manrope: ["Manrope"],
    },
    colors: {
      "core-border-primary-10": "#CFE1F7",
      "alopay-blue": "#1382FB",
      "alopay-blue-3": "#005ABD",
      "alopay-blue-2": "#405B84",
      "alopay-blue-1": "#85ADD5",
      "alopay-blue-0": "#B3CAE6",
      "alopay-light-blue": "#4EB2F9",
      "alopay-light-blue-1": "#B5D9FF",
      "alopay-light-2": "#F2F5FF",
      "alopay-light-1": "#E2E5EF",
      "alopay-light-0": "#F3F4F7",
      "alopay-white": "#FFFFFF",
      "alopay-red-1": "#C72F1F",
      "alopay-red-0": "#EB4E45",
      "alopay-green": "#468F2B",
      "alopay-green-0": "#4EA20C",
      "alopay-yellow": "#FFB600",
      "alopay-dark-dim": "#7499BE",
      "alopay-dark-blue": "#0C0C3B",
      "programs-custom-blue-white": "#F4F6FA",
      transparent: "transparent",
      "core-border-primary-0": "#EBF4FF",
    },
    borderRadius: {
      none: "0",
      xs: "0.25rem",
      sm: "0.5rem",
      full: "12.5rem",
      circle: "999px",
    },
    extend: {
      boxShadow: {
        xs: "0px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), 0px 8px 24px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)",
        "revert-xs": "0px -2px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        qrZone:
          "linear-gradient(193deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20) -13.83%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 99.72%)",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: ["@tailwindcss/line-clamp", require("daisyui")],
  daisyui: {
    darkTheme: "light",
    logs: false,
  },
};
```

Tailwind css Intellisense is working with daisyui

Answer (score 0):

> "editor.quickSuggestions": {
> "strings": "on"   }

For me this code worked like a charm.